# SwiftUI Crash after accessing DisplayListGraphicsRenderer and DisplayListViewUpdater multiple times

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Our app crashes on a specific iOS Version (iOS Version 16.0.3) and all I see in the crash logs is following. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the crash in any test device or simulator and the given test device is 3000 km away from me.

DisplayListGraphicsRenderer.swift and DisplayListViewUpdater.swift are accessed multiple times and app crashes after that.

Anyone had a similar issue?

```
  Thread 20 name:
        Thread 20 Crashed:
    0   RenderBox                       0x000000021839c2f4 0x21833a000 + 402164
    1   RenderBox                       0x000000021839bce0 0x21833a000 + 400608
    2   RenderBox                       0x000000021839f3c0 0x21833a000 + 414656
    3   RenderBox                       0x000000021839f838 0x21833a000 + 415800
    4   RenderBox                       0x0000000218368a50 0x21833a000 + 191056
    5   RenderBox                       0x00000002183688a8 0x21833a000 + 190632
    6   SwiftUI                         0x00000001bc6e7a3c @nonobjc RBDisplayListInterpolator.__allocating_init(from:to:options:) + 140 (<compiler-generated>:0)
    7   SwiftUI                         0x00000001bba0c808 DisplayList.GraphicsRenderer.render(item:in:) + 5088 (DisplayListGraphicsRenderer.swift:222)
    8   SwiftUI                         0x00000001bba33424 DisplayList.GraphicsRenderer.render(list:in:) + 552 (DisplayListGraphicsRenderer.swift:102)
 ...
DisplayList.GraphicsRenderer.render(list:in:) + 552 (DisplayListGraphicsRenderer.swift:102)
    79  SwiftUI                         0x00000001bc248504 closure #1 in DisplayList.ViewUpdater.InterpolatorCache.interpolator(from:to:transition:progress:contentSeed:state:index:updateProgress:) + 132 (DisplayListViewCache.swift:528)
    80  SwiftUI                         0x00000001bc6e77cc specialized DisplayList.GraphicsRenderer.render(at:do:) + 132 (DisplayListGraphicsRenderer.swift:75)
    81  SwiftUI                         0x00000001bc247050 DisplayList.ViewUpdater.InterpolatorCache.interpolator(from:to:transition:progress:contentSeed:state:index:updateProgress:) + 520 (DisplayListViewCache.swift:525)
    82  SwiftUI                         0x00000001bc246c84 DisplayList.ViewUpdater.ViewCache.prepare(item:parentState:interpolatorCache:) + 344 (DisplayListViewCache.swift:118)
    83  SwiftUI                         0x00000001bb973768 

 ...
DisplayList.ViewUpdater.updateAsync(oldList:oldParentState:newList:newParentState:) + 592 (DisplayListViewUpdater.swift:281)
    508 SwiftUI                         0x00000001bb9747cc DisplayList.ViewUpdater.updateInheritedViewAsync(oldItem:oldParentState:newItem:newParentState:) + 1976 (DisplayListViewUpdater.swift:396)
    509 SwiftUI                         0x00000001bb9737e8 DisplayList.ViewUpdater.updateAsync(oldList:oldParentState:newList:newParentState:) + 592 (DisplayListViewUpdater.swift:281)
```

Comment: We're seeing the same issue but no luck in finding out what the cause is.

Comment: @KunalShah In our case an external library UserCentrics was presenting itself on another view which was shown as sheet. It took me 2 days to find out the issue.
In your case this could be related with the view hierarchy as well. check if you can end up with overlapping sheets, modally presented VCs etc.